# How to create css classes which are "stronger" that elements?

Tags: css

I have one question concerning css classes and elements. Say I have something like `form input[type=submit] {...}`

Now on one page I want to add a submit button but with a different look. So I created a class for example `form .button` and added `class="button"` to a submit button. The problem is now that the settings of `form input[type=submit] {...}` seem to be stronger so that the button with the class looks the same. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about specificity. `form input[type=submit]` is more specific, so will override a class.  If you use an id on your element it will be more specific still, and so will override your general rule.

```
form #submitButton {
    /* strongly specific rules */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
form input[type=submit] {
    border: 3px solid red
}
form input.button {
    border: 3px solid blue
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/5pbbD/

This problem is all about CSS Specificity. See [this article](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity/) and [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

- `form input[type=submit]` has greater specificity than `form .button`, so that's why you're having this problemn.
- I've changed the second selector (`form .button`) into `form input.button`, which is just specific enough. The two selectors in my answer actually have *equal* specificity, so it comes down to the order they're defined.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about [CSS selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). Easy solution for your problem:

```
form input[type=submit].button {
    /* ... */
}
```

*Please* **don't** just use `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the attributes in the class with !important, i.e.

```
.button
{
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

That could do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use,

```
form input[type=submit].button,
form .button {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to the button that you want different and change the CSS concerning the other buttons to be applied to "everything but buttons with this class". You can find out how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726493/negative-css-selectors/726525#726525).

Answer (score -1):

use `!important`  css directive

Comment: _[Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)_

Comment: David Thomas's answer to this question explains very well why !important should be used as little as possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524175/why-doesnt-new-styling-appear-in-browser-when-class-is-added-to-element/6524213#6524213